# pylab.savefig() narrows some pixel rows and columns when saving as .png or .tiff but not at .pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, png, pixel

`pylab.show()` has the following (good) output:
[`pylab.show()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBAEi.jpg)
But `pylab.savefig("figure.png")` has the following (wrong) output:
[`pylab.savefig("figure.png")`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abTTB.jpg)
There is a column in which the pixels are narrower. In the rest of the figure there are also rows were the the pixels are narrower, this happens every few rows/columns.

I have tried various options for savefig but none resolved the problem of the narrow pixels.

Copy paste and compile code:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

dir_plots = 'path/'
if not os.path.exists(dir_plots):
    os.makedirs(dir_plots)  
image_data=np.zeros([3600,1800])
for i in range(3600):
    for j in range(1800):
        if (i+j)%2==0:
            image_data[i][j]=10

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(36, 18))

image1 =imshow((image_data[:,:].T),cmap=cm.jet,vmin = 0, vmax = 10,interpolation='none',aspect='equal')

pl.savefig(dir_plots+'stackoverflow_self_contained.png',dpi=80)
pl.show()
pl.close()
print 'done'
```

In the comment someone suggested to use dpi = 80, I did the following:

```
pl.savefig(dir_plots+'stackoverflow dpi.png',dpi=80)
```

But with no result.

Update: I figured out that it only happens at the formats that lose information: .png .tiff but not at .pdf
Hope that anyone can help.

Regards,

Jens Wagemaker

Comment: It might help if you included some self-contained code and data so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also try passing a dpi to `savefig` for historical reasons the default figure dpi is 80, and the default savefig dpi is 100.

Comment: Hi @tfv , I have included some self contained code, is it good like this?

Comment: Hi @tcaswell , as you can see the dpi=80 did not work.

Comment: Can you please make the code copy-paste runnable?

Comment: @tcaswell I have made the code copy-paste runnable, thanks